# Make row of div horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a row of around 6 `divs`. Currently if the row of divs suppresses the width of the page, it puts the next div under the rest, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7giQ.png)

My question is: **how do I have a row of horizontal divs with a scroll bar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Wvp.png) **

Here's my code:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <span>Example</span>
        <br>
        <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .box {
        float: left; 
        width: 127px; 
        margin: 9.2px;
        border: 5px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpHv/59/

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all `<div class="box">` into one more div and add width in px

```css
.box {
 float: left; 
 width: 127px; 
 margin: 9.2px;
 border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div style="width: 1000px;">

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>

<div class="box">
<span>Example</span>
<br>
<img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/photos/display_pic_with_logo/59156/113033326.jpg" width="50" height="80" />
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
.parentdiv {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 450px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box{
    width: 127px;
    margin: 9.2px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```